# Julia charting interaction

Tags: charts, julia

I am looking for a Julia charting package that allows the user to click on a point in the chart (a bar in a barplot for example).  Then send an event that I can interactively receive and interpret which bar was clicked on to then produce another chart of whatever I would like.

I have found interactive Julia packages which go the other way.   Put a widget on the screen and the user can change a slider for example to change chart.  But not clicking on chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PyPlot` wraps matplotlib, and matplotlib supports event handling. Read the [matplotlib event handling docs here](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html). This is has all the functionality from their first example translated into Julia. You may want to refer to the `[PyCall` docs][2](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) to read about the `pyobject[:symbol]` syntax.

```
julia> using PyPlot
julia> fig=figure()
PyPlot.Figure(PyObject <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x1159d3f90>)
julia> function onclick(event)
       println(event)
       println((event[:xdata],event[:ydata],event[:x],event[:y]))
       end
onclick (generic function with 1 method)
julia> fig[:canvas][:mpl_connect]("button_press_event",onclick)
6
julia> PyObject <matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent object at 0x131d5d110>
(nothing, nothing, 385, 388.0)
PyObject <matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent object at 0x131d5d410>
(nothing, nothing, 365, 256.0)
PyObject <matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent object at 0x131d5d3d0>
(nothing, nothing, 429, 337.0)
```

The last six lines are from me clicking randomly on the blank figure that appeared. I suggest looking at the "Object Picking" section.