# How to interact with a plot/figure in Julia

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia

I'm (ultra) new to Julia and I'm trying to figure out how to interact with a plot. To be more specific, currently I use Pyplot do display different kinds of data (in one instance I just plot multiple curves via plot() and in the other I plot the values of a 2d array as heatmaps via imshow()).

I want to be able to click on these images and handle the clicking as event in the code. Upon searching I only find old posts that say "this is currently not featured". 
Does anyone have suggestions on where to look/ what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/Interact.jl

Comment: I also saw this, but as far as I can see in the readme it doesn't help to generate an event. I want to click on specific points and have their (x,y) coordinates to work with in the code.

Comment: See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189612/julia-charting-interaction

Comment: Yes, and also it woud be nice to have sliders, checkboxes, tabs, uitrees, etc. But for now there are very slow plots in JuliaPro (taking up to minutes to precompile for me and seconds to call first time).

Comment: I did this for a phase portrait interactive plot
https://gist.github.com/elsuizo/0c32a6331935938d8ce1974804426162

Comment: Thank you guys, that does the trick!